# Microstates in a quantum gas and the occupation number

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, fermions, quantum-states, bosons

The occupation number of a gas of fermions or bosons is typically defined as:

$$\bar{n} = \sum_n n\ p_n$$

where n is the number of particles in each state.

But $n$ is just a number of fermions (or bosons) in some particular cell of position-momentum space. So why can't many different states contain the same number of particles? What is the motivation behind summing over each number of accessible number of particles in any state (0, 1 - for fermions and $\Bbb{N}$ for bosons)?

*Edit. I'm following [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3030024288). $p_n$ is the probability that a given state is occupied, given by Boltzmann distribution. The very reason this question might lack some detail is because I was not fully understanding the subject at the time and thus was asking for help. Now I would like to answer my own question once it's reopened.*

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which book are you following? What is $p_n$? And if $\bar n$ is an occupation number, why it does not have any index referring to the single particle state in question (as e.g. in the Fermi-Dirac or Bose-Einstein distribution)?

Comment: @TobiasFünke I made an edit

Comment: But *what* do you mean with "that a given state is occupied"? There is some index missing, I suppose. And shouldn't it be that $p_n$ gives the probability that a given state is occupied by $n$-particles instead?!

Comment: Yes, I think $p_n$ really means the probability that a given state is occupied by $n$
particles instead. So, the occupation number is defined as follows: we consider an arbitrary state, then it can be occupied by any natural number $n$ of particles with probability $p_n$, so we simply get a mean number for that state. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The occupation number is defined as a mean number of particles in a particular single state in particle's position-momentum space. So we just take the average over all possible numbers of particles in this state weigthed by the probability of that number of particles being present in that state.